# Angular Replace String with RouterLink

Tags: angular

I created a pipe in angular in order to find if a specific string is found. I would like to then replace the string with a routerLink to another page in my application. So far my pipe returns this this:

```
return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(_.replace(value, regeExp, replacedString => {
    return `<a [routerLink]=['/test']>${replacedString}<a/>`;
}));
```

This is being showing in a table cell like this:

`<mat-cell *matCellDef="let data" [innerHTML]="data.id | urlPipe"></mat-cell>`

It does replace the string with a hyperlink but if I click on it nothing happens so I am assuming you can't replace with a routerLink? I am not sure how else to do this.